# Admin access c#/vb

Tags: c#, .net

How to get admin Access in my Project?

```
FileStream fs=new FileStream("c:/samplehubdata.xml",
                         FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                         FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                         FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this to get admin access to write on C

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

to your app.manifest You can create this file if you are not able to see the app.manifest. If you want to know more about the app.manifest you can look here

//edited because he wanted to know how

Go to your project and click add
Select Visual C# Items
Select "Application Manifest File"
Call this app.manifest (I guess it is by default)